# Display selected SVG paths on top of darkness overlay + Stop jQuery looped function

Tags: jquery, css, svg

Creating a highlight effect for SVG paths with the same class name. Trying to achieve a [result like this](http://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/LkaYOW). Where the other elements (not hovered) are covered by darkness overlay.

[image: darkness overlay with z-index higher elements highlight]

Z-index trouble with SVG paths to be on top of darkness overlay. Think the overlay is causing the loop function problem? Any suggestions or alternatives to z-index or similar overlay highlight effect?
[Semi working pen here.](http://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/zBVwqk)

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.orange-cell, .green-cell, .purple-cell, .white-cell').hover(function() {
        var colorClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];       
        $("."+colorClass ).addClass('z-relative');
        $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 1);
    },function() {var colorClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        $("."+colorClass ).removeClass('z-relative');
        $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```